# Populating a table inside a Lua function isn't reflected outside

Tags: function, reference, lua, lua-table

I'm trying to populate a table inside one function and then use the values it received in a later call, removing each value after it has been used. For some reason the values aren't persisting between function calls. The tables that hold the handles should be populated when `subscribeToService()` is called and then depopulated in `unsubscribeToService()`.

```
local subscriptionSignals_AudioMixerManager = {"volumeLevel", "muteStatus", "fadeLevel", "balanceLevel", "bassLevel", "trebleLevel", "midLevel", "AVCLevel", "activeAudioSrc", "interruptSrc"}
local signalHandlers_AudioMixerManager = {["volumeLevel"] = OnSignal, ["muteStatus"] = OnSignal, ["fadeLevel"] = onSignal, ["balanceLevel"] = OnSignal, ["bassLevel"] = OnSignal, ["trebleLevel"] = OnSignal, ["midLevel"] = OnSignal, ["AVCLevel"] = OnSignal, ["activeAudioSrc"] = OnSignal, ["interruptSrc"] = OnSignal}
local subscriptionHandles_AudioMixerManager = {}

local subscriptionSignals_AudioManager = {"targetSource"}
local signalHandlers_AudioManager = {["targetSource"] = onAudioSourceChange}
local subscriptionHandles_AudioManager = {}

local function subscribeToService(objectPath, signalNames, signalHandlers, subscriptionHandles)
    print("Subscribing...")
    for i,v in ipairs(signalNames) do
            subscriptionHandles[v] = service.subscribe(objectPath, v, signalHandlers[v]);
            print(v .. " handle: ")
            print(subscriptionHandles[v])
        end
    print("Done subscribing")
end

local function unsubscribeFromService(subscriptionHandles)
    print("Unsubscribing...")
    for i,v in ipairs(subscriptionHandles) do
            print("Entered for loop")
            service.unsubscribe(v)
            print(v)
            subscriptionHandles[i] = nil
        end
    print("Done unsubscribing")
end

local function subscribe()
    subscribeToService(AudioMixerManager, subscriptionSignals_AudioMixerManager, signalHandlers_AudioMixerManager, subscriptionHandles_AudioMixerManager)
    subscribeToService(AudioManager, subscriptionSignals_AudioManager, signalHandlers_AudioManager, subscriptionHandles_AudioManager)

    local result, error = service.invoke(AudioMixerManager, "registerMuteClient", {serviceName="audioSettings-interrupt"})
    muteClientID = result.id
    result, error = service.invoke(AudioMixerManager, "registerMuteClient", {serviceName="audioSettings-modechange"})
    muteClientID2 = result.id
end

local function unsubscribe()
    unsubscribeFromService(subscriptionHandles_AudioMixerManager);
    unsubscribeFromService(subscriptionHandles_AudioManager);
end
```

I get the following as output when `subscribe()` is called and then later `unsubscribe()`

```
Subscribing...
volumeLevel handle:
userdata: 18f418
muteStatus handle:
userdata: 18f490
fadeLevel handle:
userdata: 18f508
balanceLevel handle:
userdata: 18f580
bassLevel handle:
userdata: 18f5f8
trebleLevel handle:
userdata: 18f670
midLevel handle:
userdata: 18f6e8
AVCLevel handle:
userdata: 18f760
activeAudioSrc handle:
userdata: 18f7d8
interruptSrc handle:
userdata: 18f850
Done subscribing
Subscribing...
targetSource handle:
userdata: 18f8c8
Done subscribing

Unsubscribing...
Done unsubscribing
Unsubscribing...
Done unsubscribing
```

It looks like it's not even entering the for loop in `unsubscribeFromService()` which I believe means that the table it's being passed is empty for some reason. Is there ever a situation where a table wouldn't be passed by reference in Lua? It might explain this behavior as I've broken down the smaller components and tested them individually and they seem to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a basic error just overcomplicated by the amount of code you have there. consider this simplified example:

```
local t = {}
t["asdf"] = {}

for i,v in ipairs(t) do
    print(i, v)
end
```

this doesn't print anything! but what gives? there is definitely something in t!

the issue is that ipairs() only iterates over the *numeric* indices in a table, but you are inserting values using string keys. either you will need to switch to using pairs() instead, or insert values into your subscriptionHandles table by using a numeric index (probably not what you want).

Comment: Thanks! I just figured it out right before checking back here.

Comment: @user1510964: If you really wanted to thank him, you'd accept his answer by clicking the green checkmark beside it.

Answer (score 2):

A table is always passed by reference in Lua. This means that what's happening between the `subscribe()` and `unsubscribe()` calls is either:

- `subscriptionHandles_AudioMixerManager` and `subscriptionHandles_AudioManager` are assigned an empty table.
- all elements of `subscriptionHandles_AudioMixerManager` and `subscriptionHandles_AudioManager` are set to nil.